# Adding new fields to Admin User Info in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, admin

By default when you try to add a new User in magento, it accepts only the following fields:
Username, FirstName, LastName, Email, New Password and Password Confirmation.
I want to add some more field here, e.g. About Me, PhoneNumber, etc where we will add additional information about this role specific users we add to magento.
Has anyone already done this? How should I go about doing this?
I know additional fields will need to be created in the database. The adminhtml userinfo.phtml doesn't mention fields like Username, FirstName etc, so where it is picking it up from?

Please advice.

Thanks,
Neet

Answer (score 0):

You can start with following tutorial to create registration field

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/customers_and_accounts/registration_fields

Comment: The link provided is redirected to 404.

Answer (score 0):

a) [Adding new fields to Admin User Info in magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20118309/adding-new-fields-to-admin-user-info-in-magento)

b) Adding new fields to Admin User Info in Magento

You will need to add a column to the admin_user table. Make a table with the following code:

```
<?php
$installer->getConnection()->addColumn($installer->getTable('admin/user'),
'location', array(
    'type' => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
    'length' => 256,
    'nullable' => true,
    'default' => null
));
?>
```

Then, if you want to add/edit this field from the backend you need to
rewrite the method Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Account_Edit_Form::_prepareForm and add a new
element in there:

```
<?php
 $fieldset->addField('location', 'select', array(
            'name'      => 'location',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Location'),
            'id'        => 'location',
            'title'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Location'),
            'class'     => 'input-select',
            'style'     => 'width: 80px',
            'options'   => array('1' =>
Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Russia'), '0' =>
Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('India')),
        ));

?>
```

Clear the cache and run the code. You can add new fields to Admin User Info in Magento.